# Different solutions of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I solved the following equation:

$\sin^2(2x)+\sin^2(4x)=1$

by transforming it to

$\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(8x)}{2}=1$

$\cos(4x)+\cos(8x)=0$

$\cos(2x)\cos(6x)=0$

Therefore,

$x_k=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{k\pi}{6}$ and $x_n=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{n\pi}{2}$.

But the solution in the book is entirely different, because of a completely different transformation:

[image]

So, they end up getting *three solutions* which are not like mine. Are both ways correct/complete?

Comment: How did you get $\cos 4x \times \cos 8x =0$ ? Or did you mean $2x$ and $6x$ ? If this, then your solution should be ok.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant that, but I made a mistake because I copied the code :)

Answer (score 1):

$\cos2x=0\Rightarrow2x=\pm\frac \pi2+n.2\pi$

And similarly for the $\cos6x$ term, so there should be no inconsistency in the sets of solutions